# Node JSON API testing

Tags: json, node.js, rest, testing

I'm looking for a framework to use to test a server. The server will provide a variety of services based around REST with JSON payloads. The server is written in node.js (Which I'm still learning).

I've been trying out [APIEasy](https://github.com/flatiron/api-easy) but have run into it's limitations in that it cannot pass data from test to test. I'm also not convinced that [vows](http://vowsjs.org/) (which apiary is based on) is really making my life any easier.

So I'm looking for any recommendations that people have for the following criteria:

1. Provide both console and some other output format that a CI Server can understand. I want to be able to run manually form the command line and automatically from a CI box.
2. Provides a simple "syntax" for making REST requests to a server with JSON payloads.
3. Can pass data between tests. This allows me to make a call to create a record, get back it's id and then use that in a subsequent test.
4. Is written as a javascript node package. This last is simply because I prefer to have test frameworks in the same language and API as the code being tested. Makes things a lot simpler in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended up using Restify http clients and mocka.